# LoRa and Spirit1 FSK communication issues

Tags: c, lora

I can send data from STM32WL55JC1 to Spirit1. However, I can't receive data from Spirit1 to STM32WL55JC1 and get interrupt from LoRa. Interrupt is always zero. The communication modulation is GFSK.

Also, I need some resources about STM32WL55JC1 and Spirit1.

Thank you.

Here are LoRa modulations parameters:

```
#define RF_FREQUENCY 868000000 /* Hz */
#define TX_OUTPUT_POWER 14 /* dBm */
#define FSK_FDEV 20000 /* Hz */
#define FSK_DATARATE 38400 /* bps */
#define FSK_BANDWIDTH 100000 /* Hz */
#define FSK_PREAMBLE_LENGTH 5 /* Same for Tx and Rx */
#define FSK_SYNCWORD_LENGTH 4
#define PAYLOAD_LEN 25
#define MAX_DATA_LEN 32

SUBGRF_SetBufferBaseAddress( 0x00,0x80 );
SUBGRF_SetRfFrequency(RF_FREQUENCY); //NOT THESE
SUBGRF_SetRfTxPower(TX_OUTPUT_POWER);
SUBGRF_SetStopRxTimerOnPreambleDetect(false);

ModulationParams_t modParams;
modParams.PacketType = PACKET_TYPE_GFSK;
modParams.Params.Gfsk.Bandwidth = SUBGRF_GetFskBandwidthRegValue(FSK_BANDWIDTH);
modParams.Params.Gfsk.BitRate = FSK_DATARATE;
modParams.Params.Gfsk.Fdev = FSK_FDEV;
modParams.Params.Gfsk.ModulationShaping = MOD_SHAPING_G_BT_1;
SUBGRF_SetModulationParams(&modParams);

packetParams.PacketType = PACKET_TYPE_GFSK;
packetParams.Params.Gfsk.AddrComp = RADIO_ADDRESSCOMP_FILT_OFF;
packetParams.Params.Gfsk.CrcLength = RADIO_CRC_OFF;
packetParams.Params.Gfsk.DcFree = RADIO_DC_FREE_OFF;
packetParams.Params.Gfsk.HeaderType = RADIO_PACKET_VARIABLE_LENGTH;
packetParams.Params.Gfsk.PayloadLength = PAYLOAD_LEN;
packetParams.Params.Gfsk.PreambleLength = (FSK_PREAMBLE_LENGTH << 3); //bytes to bits!!
packetParams.Params.Gfsk.PreambleMinDetect = RADIO_PREAMBLE_DETECTOR_OFF; //RADIO_PREAMBLE_DETECTOR_08_BITS;
packetParams.Params.Gfsk.SyncWordLength = (FSK_SYNCWORD_LENGTH << 3);
SUBGRF_SetPacketParams(&packetParams);
SUBGRF_SetSyncWord((uint8_t[]){0x88, 0x88, 0x88, 0x88});
//SUBGRF_SetWhiteningSeed(0x01FF);
SUBGRF_SetTxParams(RFO_LP, 14, RADIO_RAMP_40_US); //default comment
```

I am trying to develop a Local Sensor Network example that is in the Stm32wljc1 Library. Receive Function was added by me:

```c
    SUBGRF_SetDioIrqParams(IRQ_RX_DONE | IRQ_RX_TX_TIMEOUT, IRQ_RX_DONE | IRQ_RX_TX_TIMEOUT, IRQ_RADIO_NONE, IRQ_RADIO_NONE);
    SUBGRF_SetSwitch(NULL, RFSWITCH_RX);
    packetParams.Params.Gfsk.PayloadLength = 32;
    SUBGRF_SetPacketParams(&packetParams);
    RadioStandby();
    SUBGRF_SetRx(0);
    uint8_t *rLen;
    SUBGRF_GetPayload(rxData,rLen,255);
    SUBGRF_GetRxBufferStatus(rLen,rxData);
    uint8_t rssiValue = SUBGRF_GetRssiInst();
    uint8_t packetType = SUBGRF_GetPacketType();
    SUBGRF_ClearIrqStatus(IRQ_RADIO_ALL);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    RadioSleep();
```

Comment: "LoRa" is a communication stack, not a product. So "get interrupt from LoRa" doesn't make sense. Which module are you using, more specifically? And what makes you think the problem must be related to software?

Comment: That's my first post and I am a beginner. Thank you for comment. I edited post.